# Computing DFT by definition with C++

Tags: c++, dft

I'm trying to compute DFT and its inversion, for now by simplest method possible, but it keeps not working. And what's worse, I'm not sure of it. Here is my code:

(realnum is double, freq_func and time_func are vectors of complex)

```
freq_func toFreq(const time_func & waveform)
{
    freq_func res;
    res.resize(waveform.size());

    const realnum N = spectrum.size();

    for (size_t k = 0; k < waveform.size(); k++)
        for (size_t n = 0; n < waveform.size(); n++)
            res[k] += waveform[n] * exp(complex(0, -2*PI*n*k/N));

    return res;
}


time_func toTime(const freq_func & spectrum)
{

    freq_func res;
    res.resize(spectrum.size());

    const realnum N = spectrum.size();

    for (size_t n = 0; n < spectrum.size(); n++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < spectrum.size(); k++)
            res[n] += spectrum[k] * exp(complex(0, 2*PI*n*k/N));
        res[n] /= N;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Why does it never hold a = toTime(toFreq(a)) nor a = toFreq(toTime(a))? Why does toTime return results with considerable imaginary parts? Or should it? Some of online calculators do. And why does Wikipedia claim, that dividing by N can be moved to toFreq, or even substituted by dividing both by 1/sqrt(N), shouldn't there be only one possible definition?

Comment: When you have a complex debugging problem, try breaking it into a series of simpler problems before posting on stackoverflow. For instance, try writing some unit tests that `exp(complex(...))` really is doing what you think it is, you might be surprised. If so then you would have a much simpler problem on your hands. If not, include such info in your question. Your code sample should stand-alone -- I should be able to copy and paste it and then compile it. If not then how will someone else debug it.

Comment: If your question is really about the format of the fourier transform definition, that is a math quesiton and most likely off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `complex(0, 2*PI*n*k/N)` creates and initializes a [`complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) number with real part set to `0` and imaginary part set to `2*PI*n*k/N`. To implement the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), you'd really want to be using a complex number whose magnitude is 1, and phase is `2*PI*n*k/N`. You can do this with:

```
complex(polar(1,2*PI*n*k/N))
```

for the forward transform, and

```
complex(polar(1,-2*PI*n*k/N))
```

for the inverse transform.

As far as the Wikipedia claim is concerned, it is simply a question of definition of the DFT. Different implementations can choose different definitions and hence scaling by different factors. Normalized DFTs will choose the forward and inverse transform such that a round trip produced the original sequence (e.g. x == toTime(toFreq(x))). Other non-normalized DFTs may choose a different scaling (e.g. to save a few scaling operations when the scale is not important to the application at hand).